# Can't log in to facebook accounts using pidgin

Tags: empathy, pidgin, facebook, xmpp

I happen to have two facebook accounts and I used to chat on both of them using pidgin. Everything was working alright, until today, when I couldn't connect to one of my accounts. A `Server closed the connection` error was being displayed. My other account could log-in from pidgin just fine. But just a moment ago that other account as well failed to connect to facebook displaying an `Internal server error`. Did facebook completely withdraw support for XMPP chat? In that case is there any way to chat on facebook using pidgin or any other third party software?

Comment: Did facebook completely withdraw support for XMPP chat? They closed the 1.0 api since April 30, so probably they are starting to shut out down.

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to grant application access for Facebook account](/q/714573)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:** I've noticed that my answer below is outdated. The installation method has changed. Anyone interested in a solution to the problem should just go to the page https://github.com/jgeboski/purple-facebook and follow the instuctions written there. Therefore, my original post is useless now.

**The original post:**
I ran into the same problem this morning and I've just found a solution here: https://github.com/jgeboski/purple-facebook

It will add new Facebook protocol to Pidgin that works for me.

1. Go to the page below and download the latest **purple-facebook-*.tar.gz**
   https://github.com/jgeboski/purple-facebook/releases
2. Follow the steps written on the first page above under *Building and Installing on linux and other platforms*. It was quite difficult for me to compile it. I had to install some missing programs via Synaptic, I'm not sure which were really needed, however you are going to need **libjson-glib-dev** for sure. That was the last thing I needed to successfully configure it.
3. Scroll up to *Basic usage* and follow the last steps.

That should be it. Please, let us know how it went!

Comment: Thanks very much. The newly compiled plugin seems to have slowed pidgin down to some good extent, but it's working flawlessly.

Comment: This worked great just wanted to give the packages I had to install to get running on Xubuntu 14.04: 

sudo apt-get install pidgin-dev gfire libjson-glib-dev

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: @guyfromfl: Can you suggest an [edit] to the answer with that information, please?

Comment: @DavidFoerster I edited the answer above but it was rejected..........

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat

On April 30, 2014, facebook announced the deprecation of the XMPP Chat API as part of the release of Platform API v2.0.

After April 30th, 2015 apps will no longer be able to access the service or API. This includes both access to chat.facebook.com and the xmpp_login permission.

facebook recommend people access Facebook Messages on the desktop via Facebook.com or Messenger.com.

Comment: but there is still solution for pidgin users https://jgeboski.github.io/#package-repositories

Comment: and Empathy aslo works with faceboook

Comment: @JiříDoubravský no it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

James Geboski is now providing builds for Debian & Ubuntu, so it is now as simple as:

1. add the repository as source and install purple-facebook
2. restart pidgin
3. Edit account changing the protocol to Facebook and removign @chat.facebook.com from the username

Full instructions are here purple-facebook [Installing on *NIX](https://github.com/jgeboski/purple-facebook/wiki/Installing-on-*NIX)  wiki page.

Comment: I tried this fix on another box and it works great

Answer (score 0):

Facebook dropped their XMPP server and therefore Pidgin cannot connect to it anymore. In order to use Facebook chat in Pidgin you have to install the purple-facebook plugin.Open up a terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install purple-facebook
```

From Pidgin's main page go to <kbd>Tools</kbd>→<kbd>Accounts</kbd>→<kbd>Manage Accounts</kbd> and choose your Facebook account and hit <kbd>Modidy</kbd>. In the Protocol dropdown choose Facebook (Not Facebook XMPP) and enter your user name and password (facebook user name, email or phone will be valid user names).

Tested and working as expected.

**As of October 18, 2015, the purple-facebook was merged into the mainline Pidgin project. It will appear in the next major release of Pidgin and the above procedure will not be required.**