# How to grant application access for Facebook account

Tags: empathy, facebook, libpurple

Good day to all!

I've been trying to use Empathy for Facebook chat for quite some time now but whenever I try to enable it, I get the "Applications can no longer access your Facebook online account blah, blah, blah..." and so I tried going to Online Accounts and then grant access.  But whenever I click the button to grant access, it reverts back to "off" after maybe three seconds. What's happening and how can I solve this?

P.S.
I already tried using Pidgin but I still get the same error.  Sometimes I get the "authorization failed" error as well.

Also, I can log into my FB account using my web browser.

Comment: Can you still log into your Facebook account with a web browser? If you're already logged in there, log out and back in to check.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response! Yes, I already tried that but I still get the error. :-(

Comment: Ok, but can you log into Facebook from the web browser?

Comment: Yes,  I still can. D:

Comment: Great! So we have that ruled out. Please [edit] your question, so future readers can see this fact more easily.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't log in to facebook accounts using pidgin](http://askubuntu.com/questions/645920/cant-log-in-to-facebook-accounts-using-pidgin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*A note upfront:* It appears that Empathy doesn't support Facebook's messaging service, but [Pidgin](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pidgin/), a similar multi-messaging client based on the same library `libpurple`, does with a plug-in as described below.

> The `purple-facebook` plugin is a replacement for the builtin Facebook XMPP plugin. Facebook is in the process of shutting down their XMPP service, which will inevitably break existing support.

([Source](https://github.com/jgeboski/purple-facebook/wiki))

The following instructions are written for Pidgin and while they should work for the same for Empathy in theory (since they're both based on `libpurple`), people report that Empathy doesn't accept this plug-in for some reason.

> To install `purple-facebook` in Ubuntu, Linux Mint and derivatives, you can use its official repository. To add the repository and install the plugin, use the following commands:
>
> ```sh
> sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jgeboski/xUbuntu_$(lsb_release -rs)/ /"
> wget -O- 'https://jgeboski.github.io/obs.key' | sudo apt-key add -
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install purple-facebook
> ```
>
> If you don’t want to add the PPA, you can download the DEB from [HERE](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jgeboski/) (but you won’t receive any updates unless you add the repository). Or, grab the [source](https://github.com/jgeboski/purple-facebook/releases) and [build it](https://github.com/jgeboski/purple-facebook/wiki/Building-on-*NIX) yourself. […]
>
> **Once** installed, add a new account in Pidgin (*Accounts* > *Manage Accounts* > *Add*) and in the Protocol dropdown, select “Facebook”
>   (**important: NOT “Facebook (XMPP)”**):
>
> Pidgin Facebook I should also mention that in the username field, you can enter either your emil, your Facebook username or phone number associated with your Facebook account.

([Source](http://digital-era.net/use-facebook-chat-in-pidgin-with-purple-facebook/) with some modifications)

- [Official installation instructions](https://jgeboski.github.io/#package-repositories)

---

> As of October 18, 2015, jgeboski's GSoC work was merged into the mainline Pidgin project. It will appear in the next major release of Pidgin.

This means, future libpurple versions in Ubuntu (and probably earlier in the [Pidgin PPA](https://launchpad.net/~pidgin-developers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)) will include `purple-facebook` and supersede the above procedure.

Comment: Hey!  This solved it!  Didn't work with Empathy though.  But it worked for Pidgin!

Comment: Still doesn't work with Empathy or GOA but yeah, with Pidgin it's okay.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly - Facebook changed their API, which effectively prevented several packages from accessing your account and utilizing the API options - such as chat.

You can find more information with a simple Google search, for example: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/04/facebook-chat-api-empathy-pidgin-stop-working

Last I heard, Pidgin and Empathy teams are working on a solution, I wish them the best of luck too.

Comment: Ohhh. I saw this article before but dismissed  it since it was published way back April but apparently it's still the issue. :[

Can you suggest an alternative then? I don't really go on the website to browse or anything. I mainly use FB for chatting with friends, therefore, I really liked Pidgin/Empathy which allowed me to chat with them without going to the website itself. :[

Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer my question! :]

Answer (score 0):

1. I follow the steps for installing The purple-facebook plugin for
   Pidgin.
2. I install Pidgin.
3. Created facebook account in Pidgin.
4. In Empathy, import the facebook account from Pidgin. 5- Removed
   Pidgin software after facebook account imported.

And its working